# Is it possible to convert a HOAS function to continuation passing style?

Tags: haskell, continuation-passing

Mind the following Haskell program:

```
-- A HOAS term, non-polymorphic for simplicity
data Term
  = Lam (Term -> Term)
  | App Term Term
  | Num Int

-- Doubles every constant in a term
fun0 :: Term -> Term
fun0 (Lam b)   = Lam (\ x -> fun0 (b x))
fun0 (App f x) = App (fun0 f) (fun0 x)
fun0 (Num i)   = Num (i * 2)

-- Same function, using a continuation-passing style
fun1 :: Term -> (Term -> a) -> a
fun1 (Lam b)   cont = undefined
fun1 (App f x) cont = fun1 f (\ f' -> fun1 x (\ x' -> cont (App f' x')))
fun1 (Num i)   cont = cont (Num (i * 2))

-- Sums all nums inside a term
summ :: Term -> Int
summ (Lam b)   = summ (b (Num 0))
summ (App f x) = summ f + summ x
summ (Num i)   = i

-- Example
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let term = Lam $ \ x -> Lam $ \ y -> App (App x (Num 1)) (App y (Num 2))
  print (summ term)                 -- prints 3
  print (summ (fun0 term))          -- prints 6
  print (fun1 term $ \ t -> summ t) -- a.hs: Prelude.undefined
```

Here, `Term` is a (non-polymorphic) λ-term with numeric constants, and `fun0` is a function that doubles all constants inside a term. Is it possible to rewrite `fun0` in a continuation-passing style? In other words, is it possible to complete the `undefined` case of the `fun1` function such that it behaves identically to `fun0` and such that the last `print` outputs `6`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert this function to CPS, you need to also convert the function *within* the data type:

```
data Term' a
  = Lam' (Term' a -> (Term' a -> a) -> a)
  | App' (Term' a) (Term' a)
  | Num' Int
```

Then you can write your `fun1` accordingly:

```
fun1 :: Term' a -> (Term' a -> a) -> a
fun1 (Lam' b)   cont = cont (Lam' (\ x cont' -> b x cont'))
fun1 (App' f x) cont = fun1 f (\ f' -> fun1 x (\ x' -> cont (App' f' x')))
fun1 (Num' i)   cont = cont (Num' (i * 2))
```

And with the appropriate tweak to `summ`:

```
summ' :: Term' Int -> Int
summ' (Lam' b)   = b (Num' 0) summ'
summ' (App' f x) = summ' f + summ' x
summ' (Num' i)   = i
```

As well as a CPS term:

```
term' = Lam' $ \ x k -> k $ Lam' $ \ y k' -> k' $ App' (App' x (Num' 1)) (App' y (Num' 2))
```

You can run the computation just fine:

```
> fun1 term' summ'
3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to define terms in HOAS the way it is usually used, you are doing it wrong.  You shouldn't pattern match on the constructors except for in your interpreter.  The identity in HOAS looks like:

```
id2 :: Term
id2 = Lam (\x -> x)
```

In fact it is pretty common to disallow pattern matching altogether, using an interface like

```
class HOAS t where
    lam :: (t -> t) -> t
    app :: t -> t -> t
```

Notice also that the `var` case is missing -- because vars are always provided as an argument to `lam`.

The trick in HOAS is to use Haskell's lambda to implement the target language's lambda, so you can essentially write terms in bare lambda calculus (plus some extra syntax).

---

If you *must* have your question answered, there are lots of ways to do it. Both of your identity functions are not HOAS implementations of the lambda calculus identity function in your target language, but implementations of the Haskell identity function acting on `Term`s.  Your first `id0` is literally equal to

```
id0' :: Term -> Term
id0' = id
```

And your second is shaping up to be equal to

```
id1' :: Term -> (Term -> a) -> a
id1' t cont = cont t
```

(this latter case will differ in strictness, I think)

Notice these have nothing to do with the `Term` type, so you are just working hard for no reason.

I don't believe it is possible to fill in the missing case of `id1` with anything other than

```
id1 (Lam b) cont = cont (Lam b)
```

because the `Term -> Term` does not provide as "escape mechanism" for the `a` continuation result type -- `a` could be something that `Term` cannot represent, such as `IO ()`.

Comment: This is a very nice and informative answer, but it ultimately avoids answering the question; for example, `id1' t cont = cont t` wouldn't work if the function did any useful work with the input. Because of that, I've changed the question to be more precise and objective. Under that point of view, the most relevant part of your answer is the claim that this is impossible. If that is true, **that** is the correct answer, so I'd edit the `id0'` and `id1'` proposals out and leave just your reasoning for why this is impossible.

Comment: Just to be clear, this has nothing to do with functions for the Term type itself, it is merely being used as an example of a high-order datatype. I'm ultimately trying to determine if this is a counter-example to the hypothesis that *every recursive function can be converted to CPS*. If `fun0` can't be written in CPS, then there are definitely some recursive functions that can't be written in CPS.

Comment: @MaiaVictor, oh, you could have asked that directly, I assumed you were trying to learn about HOAS.  My intuitive sense is that the answer is "yes, it can, but it requires rewriting types all the types involved".  So since you are not rewriting the `Term -> Term` member of `Term`, the CPS transformation is blocked.  If you used a CPS version of `Term r = Lam (Term -> (Term -> r) -> r) | ...` then it would again be possible.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. So it seems true that `fun1` can't be written for this `Term` datatype, but it could have been for a CPS version of the datatype itself. This is a little bit underwhelming, but makes sense.